# How do I assign an HTML form's textbox contents to an VB.Net form's textbox?

Tags: html, vb.net

I have a standard HTML form that has a textbox input element on it which has some data we need to transfer to an asp:textbox via a VB.Net procedure. I want to transfer the HTML form's textbox value to the asp:form's textbox.

How do you write that qualified HTML form-and-textbox reference in VB.Net?

Comment: Could you add your code to give more insight please?

Comment: Here's the html form. I want to transfer the value of MyInputElement on this form into an asp:textbox in the MyReturns.aspx page (the action tag's target page) using vb code in the page load event procedure.

<form action="MyReturns.aspx" method="POST" id="myform">
<span class="my-errors"></span>
 
<div class="form-row">
<label>
<span>Number</span>
<input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number" id="MyInputElement"/>
</label>
</div>

<button type="submit">Submit Numbers</button>
</form>

Comment: Adding code in your original question through an Edit would make it much easier to read. You can always add runat="server" tag to most any control in order to access it on postback in the vb code.

Comment: Solution was this: request.form("<html objectname>"). 

The reason I had to use a standard html posting form was because I was not allowed to name objects and have them hit our server for a background procedure to run-- there are security standards that had to be met in our case. A standard html post with an action tag will send the posting form's values to the url supplied in the action tag, without first sending to our server. A "runat" or "<asp:textbox id="nmbox">" calls our server and would've provided a handle for tapping our datastream. Request.Form/name tag value gave me data safely.